# Enemy AI with Rigidbody - Floating in the air

Tags: c#, unity

I'm working on my enemy AI scripts and I'm using a rigidbody to have the enemies chase the player when the player gets into its aggro distance.

Two of the main problems I'm having:

1. When the game starts, all the enemies are floating in the air
2. Even when the player is outside the enemie's aggro distance, the enemy still chases the player

**Code:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    public int moveSpeed;
    public int rotationSpeed;
    public int attackSpeed; 
    public int maxDistance;
    public int aggroDistance;

    private Transform myTransform;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    private Vector3 dir;

    void Awake() {
        myTransform = transform;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Start () {
        character = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        //Find playerS
        GameObject go = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        //Set player as target
        target = go.transform;

        maxDistance = 2;
        aggroDistance = 10;
    }

    void Update() {
        dir = target.position - rb.position;
        dir.Normalize();
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(dir), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Vector3.Distance(target.position, myTransform.position) < aggroDistance) {
            if (Vector3.Distance(target.position, myTransform.position) > maxDistance) {
                rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime); 
            }
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        rb.AddForce (dir * rotationSpeed);
    }
}
```

**Enemy Properties:**
[image]

Comment: About the aggro, have you tried to output the console the different values involved in your checks? Then to use a step-by-step debugger to determine why your values are not as you expected? You should also try to add comments your parameters so that we know what they are. It's difficult to know what _maxDistance_ is exactly and what is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You are manipulating your GameObject's `RigidBody` as well as its `Transform`. This is a no-no.

From the Official Unity Documentation: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html

> Rigidbodies allow your GameObjects to act under control of the physics engine. This opens the gateway to realistic collisions, varied types of joints, and other very cool behaviors. Manipulating your GameObjects by adding forces to a Rigidbody creates a very different feel and look than adjusting the Transform Component directly. **Generally, you shouldn’t manipulate the Rigidbody and the Transform of the same GameObject - only one or the other.**

However, sometimes you will want to have objects within your game world that *can* react to physics at certain times, just not all the time. For example you may want your enemies to be controlled manually by your script when they are alive, but when they die they could become ragdolls and fall to the floor convincingly.

The way you do this is by using the **isKinematic** property on the `RigidBody`. When set to true, your GameObject will not react to physics events, however it can still cause physics events on other objects that have a `RigidBody`. So you can directly manipulate the `Transform` of an object marked **isKinematic**. This property can be manually turned on/off in your scripts.

More info on **isKinematic** here: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html

---

### What you need to do:

- On your Enemy's `RigidBody`, set **isKinematic** to true.
- Manipulate the `transform` but **not** the `rigidbody`.

When you need to, you can make your Enemy react to physics again by doing:

```
rb.isKinematic = false;
```

Now you can manipulate the `rigidbody` but **not** the `transform`.

In your code you should change

```
rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

to

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

and you should remove the code from `FixedUpdate()`.

I hope this helps you solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the FixedUpdate. Each frame you set "dir" to point towards the player and then apply a force in that direction regardless of the distance, so your rigidbody is always going to move towards the player. And you are already rotating and changing the position of the enemy in Update, so the FixedUpdate isn't needed.

Comment: He is right by doing physics stuff like forces in fixed update